# Cannot reproduce OLS result using LASSO with $\lambda=0$

Tags: matlab, least-squares, lasso

I'm using the `lasso` function in MATLAB to perform regularized regression for parameter selection. I'm new to LASSO, so I generated some toy data and tested LASSO with lambda = 0 to make sure I would get the OLS result (since there would be no penalty for model size). Unfortunately, I'm getting a value pretty close to the OLS result, but not equal to it, which puzzles me. Here is my code:

```
x0 = linspace(1, 5, 100)';
X = [x0, x0.^2, log(x0)];
B = [1 3 5]';
Y = X*B;
[B_lasso, FitInfo] = lasso(X, Y, 'alpha', 1, 'Lambda', 0, 'Standardize', 1)
B_ols = (X'*X)^-1*(X'*Y)
```

Here, B_ols = [1, 3, 5]' as expected but B_lasso = [1.14, 2.99, 4.83]'. I'd really appreciate some input as to why B_ols and B_lasso both do not equal B in the case where lambda is 0 and there is no noise added to X*B when generating Y.

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm doesn't use the normal equations to solve the least squares problem. Instead, it uses coordinate cyclic descent, which searches for the minimum with a certain precision, controlled in matlab by the parameter 'reltol'. Even though 'reltol' by default is set to 1e-4 it doesn't mean the Beta's will have the same precision.

```
[B_lasso, FitInfo] = lasso(X, Y, 'alpha', 1, 'Lambda', 0,... 
'RelTol', 1e-10, 'Standardize', 1)
```

B_lasso =

```
1.0000
3.0000
5.0000
```

FitInfo =

```
     Intercept: -1.0059e-07
        Lambda: 0
         Alpha: 1
            DF: 3
           MSE: 1.2694e-17
PredictorNames: {}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it use the normal equations? Is it easier to find multiple related solutions this way than e.g. fitting OLS each time?

Comment: @jona cause the optimization is non-linear (don't confuse it with a non-linear feature space).